# Getting "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake" on Glassfish, not using java

Tags: java, ssl, glassfish

I am getting the `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake error` when I lauch my code in glassfish, It runs well with java ...

Full stack trace:

```
2016-01-27T17:26:47.078+0100|Avertissement: Caught exception executing step: com.ibm.jbatch.container.exception.BatchContainerRuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake

at com.ibm.jbatch.container.artifact.proxy.BatchletProxy.process(BatchletProxy.java:36)
at com.ibm.jbatch.container.impl.BatchletStepControllerImpl.invokeBatchlet(BatchletStepControllerImpl.java:79)
at com.ibm.jbatch.container.impl.BatchletStepControllerImpl.invokeCoreStep(BatchletStepControllerImpl.java:107)
at com.ibm.jbatch.container.impl.BaseStepControllerImpl.execute(BaseStepControllerImpl.java:144)
at com.ibm.jbatch.container.impl.ExecutionTransitioner.doExecutionLoop(ExecutionTransitioner.java:112)
at com.ibm.jbatch.container.impl.JobThreadRootControllerImpl.originateExecutionOnThread(JobThreadRootControllerImpl.java:110)
at com.ibm.jbatch.container.util.BatchWorkUnit.run(BatchWorkUnit.java:80)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at org.glassfish.enterprise.concurrent.internal.ManagedFutureTask.run(ManagedFutureTask.java:141)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
at org.glassfish.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThread.run(ManagedThreadFactoryImpl.java:250)

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:946)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:702)
at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:122)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:295)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
at javaeetutorial.batch.webserverlog.---
at com.ibm.jbatch.container.artifact.proxy.BatchletProxy.process(BatchletProxy.java:33)
... 13 more

Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:482)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
... 23 more
```

I already spent 3 days reading all the posts. Is there something to do with that: https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21416 ?

**EDIT**
That's the code: (it crashes in glassfish at `writer.flush`)

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import javax.net.ssl.*;

public class Test {

    // substitute your own username and password
    private static final String initiation_command = "live username ***** password *******" + "\n";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String machineName = "firehose.flightaware.com";
        int port = 1501;
        RunClient(machineName, port);
        System.out.println(" Thank you for using FlightAware ... bye now");
    }

    public static void RunClient(String machineName, int port) {
        System.out.println(" Running Client");
        try {
            SSLSocket ssl_socket;
            ssl_socket = (SSLSocket) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket(machineName, port);
            // enable certifcate validation:
            SSLParameters sslParams = new SSLParameters();
            sslParams.setEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm("HTTPS");
            ssl_socket.setSSLParameters(sslParams);

            //send your initiantion command
            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(ssl_socket.getOutputStream(), "UTF8");
            writer.write(initiation_command);
            writer.flush();

            // read messages from FlightAware
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ssl_socket.getInputStream()));

            String message = null;
            int limit = 10; //limit number messages for testing
            while (limit > 0 && (message = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("msg: " + message);
            }

            //done, close everything
            writer.close();
            reader.close();
            ssl_socket.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the code in question?

Comment: Maybe the remote end did not like what it saw in the server's ciphersuite offering (no matches with it's own accepted set).

Comment: It runs OK with the jre, NOK in glassfish. On the same machine!

Comment: Runs well also in tomcat

Comment: I finally managed to mak it work. Glassfish was using it's client certificate and the server I was connecting to didn't like it. I wrote a method to replace SSLSocketFactory.getDefault() with an empty KeyManager and it works